# systemd 'Run shell script at boot as different user with login environment'

Tags: systemd

Problem: I want a shell script to run from the login environment of a different user at boot.  Here's my .service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Weather Application Server

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=weather
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/local/weather/startfeed
ExecStop=/usr/local/weather/stopfeed

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This works from the command line (i.e. typing 'systemctl start/stop weatherService').  However...when I reboot the machine, I get the following error via journalctl -se:

```
-- Subject: Unit weatherServer.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit weatherServer.service has begun starting up.
Jan 10 19:21:48 localhost.local.local systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
Jan 10 19:21:48 localhost.local.local systemd[784]: Failed at step USER  spawning /usr/local/weather/startfeed: No such file or directory
-- Subject: Process /usr/local/weather/startfeed could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
```

I'm a systemd newbe, but I've searched high and low.  Why can I run this from the command line via 'systemctl start/stop' and regular from the command line, but not from boot?

---

FIXED !!!!

SOLUTION WAS ...

The 'Unit file' configuration in my original post is correct.  The system running this is using an ActiveDirectory like process that hadn't completely started when this was being fired off.  The solution that worked for us was to add a 'timer' (i.e. a .timer file).  The weatherServer.timer file below is what worked for us:

```
[Unit]
Description=Weather Application Server Timer

[Timer]
OnBootSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Hopefully this will help someone who is also experiencing this issue.

Comment: What is unusual about your system?

Comment: @Michael Hampton --> CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core).  Besides that...I don't know.

Comment: OK, then describe the entire system top to bottom. The machine, the filesystems, everything.

Comment: After you run `systemctl start weatherService`, what new entries do you see in `journalctl -u weatherService` ?

Comment: From the command line, I get the output of the 'env' command of the weather user (that's my script at this point).  After a reboot, I get.....
Jan 10 21:47:03 localhost.local.local systemd[1]: weatherServer.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Jan 10 21:47:03 localhost.local.local systemd[1]: Failed to start Weather Application Server.
Jan 10 21:47:03 localhost.local.local systemd[1]: Unit weatherServer.service entered failed state.
Jan 10 21:47:03 localhost.local.local systemd[1]: weatherServer.service failed.

Comment: Without knowing more about the system in question, it's impossible to say anything, only to make wild guesses which are likely wrong. Since you never responded to my request for information, I must presume you are no longer attempting to solve this problem. If you are, then please edit your question appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your script is trying to run before the filesystem holding /usr/local/weather is mounted.  What you want to do is put in a dependency or two to tell systemd to wait until the filesystem is mounted before running.  This can be done by adding a `After=` line in the `[Unit]` section of your unit file.  For example:

```
[Unit]
Description=Weather Application Server
After=network.target local-fs.target
```

After making the change you will need to run `systemctl daemon-reload`, or you can just reboot to see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Nope...Here's what I got: -- Unit weatherServer.service has begun starting up.
Jan 10 20:58:09 localhost.local.local systemd[1049]: Failed at step   USER spawning /usr/local/weather/startfeed: No such file or directory
    -- Subject: Process /usr/local/weather/startfeed could not be executed
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
    --
    -- The process /usr/local/weather/startfeed could not be executed and failed.

Comment: --> Is there a 'target' I can include with the [Unit]  After=  that controls when the o.s. sees 'users'?  Make sense?

Comment: Try changing the `After=` line so it looks like this: `After=multi-user.target`.  I'm thinking there might be something running after network.target that is needed.  If that doesn't work, try running `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and see what the top-most target is in the chain.  On my system it is `graphical.target`.

Comment: Nope...    @virtex -->  Thanks so much for you help!  Very much appreciated!

Comment: This is really strange.  What happens if you disable the service (`systemctl disable weatherService`) so it doesn't start automatically at boot, then add a line (`systemctl start weatherService`) to /etc/rc.d/rc.local to run it?  Maybe also add a line there to make sure you can see the executable (`ls -l /usr/local/weather/startfeed >/tmp/startfeed.out 2>&1`) and see what gets logged to /tmp/startfeed.out.